# why do i get the protected page instead of the login page?

Tags: jsf, jboss5.x, jaas, icefaces-1.8

I'm using JAAS to secure my web-application. As the title says, the problem is that i get the home page which is in the protected folder instead of the login page. Actually the home page is my welcome page. By the way, it works fine when i write the URL (/myappJaas/protected/admin/homeadmin.xhtml) in the web browser. This is the web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/protected/admin/homeadmin.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admins</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/public/errorlogin.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose of `<welcome-file>`. It should represent the sole filename of the default index file of the directory. This file will be presented to the enduser when the enduser requests a directory. The container will then transparently dispatch the configured welcome file to the enduser without sending a redirect. However, the current URL is still in public domain.

You want to send a fullworthy redirect instead. You could do that in a filter, or by a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` in the `index.xhtml` welcome file, or in the constructor of the managed bean associated with the fictive `index.xhtml` welcome file.