# How to show full page URL of welcome file in address bar

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, welcome-file

I have "/pages/index.xhtml" page. The problem is when i run the application, this index page name doesn't appears at address bar.

It only shows `http://localhost:8080/myApplication/`. What I want to see is `http://localhost:8080/myApplication/pages/index.xhtml`

Is there any solution?

here is my welcome file from web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to send a redirect from `/` to `/pages/index.xhtml`. Easiest is to use a *real* index file with a meta refresh header for this.

First create a `/index.xhtml` file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dummy homepage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=pages/index.xhtml" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Then change your `<welcome-file>` as follows:

```
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

This also instantly fixes your bad way of using `<welcome-file>`. It's not supposed to specify the "home page", but it's supposed to specify the folder's own file which needs to be served when a folder such as `/` or `/foo/` is requested in URL instead of a file.

#### See also

- [How to use a sub-folder as web.xml welcome directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425010/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-as-web-xml-welcome-directory/16426179#16426179)
- [why do i get the protected page instead of the login page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761433/why-do-i-get-the-protected-page-instead-of-the-login-page/9762438#9762438)