# Show full URL in browser address bar when using <welcome-file>

Tags: url, jsf-2, welcome-file

I am using `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`. My welcome file is at `faces/index.xhtml`. Everything is working fine except that the full URL for the welcome file is not shown in browser address bar. When I type in

```
http://localhost:8080/hello1/
```

I want to see in browser address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/hello1/faces/index.xhtml
```

How do I get the URL to appear? Here's my web.xml code fragment

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: What about having an `index.jsp` which just redirects to `faces/index.xhtml`: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39399/2390083). BTW as for the `/faces/*` mapping, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7889247/2390083).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show full page URL of welcome file in address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047451/how-to-add-page-names-to-address-bar)